# Is there a difference between node* next and node *next?

Tags: c, data-structures

While coding a linked list I came across this confusing concept of

```
struct Node *next;
struct Node* next;
```

If there is a difference in the memory management or in any other way between the two kindly explain it diagrammatically!

Comment: If not, you still need a diagram?

Comment: These are the same: during translation the spaces are eventually removed (the declaration becomes a token sequence containing the tokens `struct`, `Node`, `*`, `next` and `;`). You could skip the space entirely since `*` will work as separating tokens (ie `struct Node*next;).

Comment: haha..obviously no if not I dnt need the diagram.!

Comment: Both are same, though I would recommend you to learn the basics tokens, separators, c semantics and grammar and all basic stuffs before moving on to structures and linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Those two declarations are equivalent.  Both declare `next` to be of type `struct Node *`.